# Elasticsearch - Filter out items based on subarray

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to only fetch Vrvriksomheds that has a 'livsforloeb' with any 'periode' with a null 'gyldigTil' value.

Current query is:

```
"query": {
      "bool": {
        "must_not": [
            {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "Vrvirksomhed.livsforloeb.periode.gyldigTil"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This works for most of the dataset, however in the cases where a Vrvirksomhed has multiple livsforloeb, where one of them has a null value in the 'gyldigTil' field, the Vrvirksomhed will not match the query. This makes sense as the field exists in one of the prior livsforloeb.

Is there a way to query out if ANY of the livsforloeb contains a null value in the 'gyldigTil' field?

Data example:

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "cvr-v-20220630",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "4006437179",
                "_score": 12.423692,
                "_source": {
                    "Vrvirksomhed": {
                        "livsforloeb": [
                            {
                                "sidstOpdateret": "2016-05-18T21:06:48.000+02:00",
                                "periode": {
                                    "gyldigFra": "2016-03-01",
                                    "gyldigTil": "2016-05-18"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "sidstOpdateret": "2018-05-01T15:09:19.000+02:00",
                                "periode": {
                                    "gyldigFra": "2018-03-01",
                                    "gyldigTil": "2018-04-30"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "sidstOpdateret": "2022-07-05T09:37:48.000+02:00",
                                "periode": {
                                    "gyldigFra": "2022-07-01",
                                    "gyldigTil": null
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You query will not work because arrays will be flattened under the hood by Elasticsearch so the field will exist.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html

You can move to a more complex structure where this doesn't happen like "nested":

**Mappings**

```
PUT test_mustnot
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Vrvirksomhed": {
        "properties": {
          "livsforloeb": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "periode": {
                "properties": {
                  "gyldigFra": {
                    "type": "date"
                  },
                  "gyldigTil": {
                    "type": "date"
                  }
                }
              },
              "sidstOpdateret": {
                "type": "date"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query**

```
POST test_mustnot/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "Vrvirksomhed.livsforloeb",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": {
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "Vrvirksomhed.livsforloeb.periode.gyldigTil"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```